# custom sign in for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Now I am using the `devise` gem, and after successful authorization it redirects user to the root page.

How to modify `sign_in` action to return json array like this: `{"auth_result":"1"}` instead of redirect?

Is it possible?
I haven't found recipes for these in devise wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise currently does not handle JSON responses - see the [issue on github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues#issue/786).  Therefore you would have to create a custom sessions_controller to handle your response.  Take a look at the [implementation on github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) to get an idea.  I threw together some rough pseudo code that will hopefully get you started:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_in
    # Remove sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource) and replace with the following, I think
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => hash_of_things_to_return.to_json }
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your routes.rb file you will have to specify your new controller - `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have successfully switched to my own auth code and I feel happy ;)