# Cannot get devise ajax to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

What I am trying to do is login via ajax, but return the form (with errors) if authentication failed. By default, `devise` will return a generic error. Here is my controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :js

  def new
    self.resource = build_resource(nil, :unsafe => true)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    render_user_form(resource, false)
  end

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#new")
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    render_user_form(resource, true)
  end

  def render_user_form(resource, success)
    render json: {
      success: success,
      content: render_to_string(partial: 'users/login_form', locals: { user: resource })
    }
  end

end
```

`new` and `create` actions are taken from `Devise::SessionsController` and customised, as advised here: [custom sign in for devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159237/custom-sign-in-for-devise)

Yet this returns an error:

```
"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
```

My js:

```
  $('#login-form').bind 'ajax:success', (xhr, data, status) ->
    alert data.content
```

Can somebody help with correctly structuring this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick was to change devise config and register:

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :json]
```

Comment: This also works when using Backbone.js to communicate with the server.  Thanks for this!